# Не могу решить ошибки при компиляции проекта в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, build-error

Сделал свое первое приложение, используя движок Unity и код c#, все готово для публикации в Play Market, но захотелось добавить рекламу от Unity Ads и вот скачал я пак из Unity Assets Store все импортировал, в коде все указал и при билде проекта мне выдало **60 ошибок**! Может кто-нибудь знает, как их убрать, ибо я сейчас в шоке.

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 60 errors

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Execution failed for task ':checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsListener found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$PlacementState found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$UnityAdsError found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.mediation.IUnityAdsExtendedListener found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.InAppPurchaseMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.MediationMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.MetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.PlayerMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :preReleaseBuild
>
> Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :checkReleaseManifest
>
> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig
>
> Task :prepareLintJar
>
> Task :generateReleaseSources

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, сами ошибки

Comment: ой, извините, не скопировал... нужно больше отдыхать

Comment: Уже переустанавливаю Unity, думаю там конфликт остаточных файлов плагина был. Я просто переустанавливал плагин и может в первый раз плохо все почистил.

Comment: другого варианта не вижу

Comment: Не нужно переустанавливать весь движок из-за плагина. В вопросе также не указаны конкретные ошибки.

Comment: я уже понял, что не указал конкретные ошибки, можете, пожалуйста, написать, что делать, когда конфликт файлов плагина на будущее

Comment: переустановка не помогла, вот ошибки

Comment: думаю, лучше добавить рекламу через Appodeal